# Inner exception returns when trying connect with Couchbase server using C#

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, nosql

Error occured when System is connecting to the Couchbase server using Couchbase.netClient. It returns error as below

```
InnerException: Couchbase.Configuration.ConfigException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message= is this a Memcached bucket?
       Source=Couchbase.NetClient
       StackTrace:
            at Couchbase.Configuration.Server.Providers.CarrierPublication.CarrierPublicationProvider.GetConfig(String bucketName, String password)
            at Couchbase.Core.ClusterController.CreateBucket(String bucketName, String password)
```

In couchbase, bucket type is Memcached. However it returns Error like "is this a Memcached bucket?". below shows App.config file and code to get clear image for this issue.

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbaseClients">
      <section name="couchbase"
               type="Couchbase.Configuration.Client.Providers.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase.NetClient"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <couchbaseClients>
    <couchbase useSsl="false">
      <servers>
        <add uri="http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools"></add>
      </servers>
      <buckets>
        <add name="testing" useSsl="false" password="12345">
          <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5" sendTimeout="12000"></connectionPool>
        </add>
      </buckets>
    </couchbase>
  </couchbaseClients>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

C# code

```
using (var cluster = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase"))
            {
                using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("testing", "12345"))
                {
                    //use the bucket here
                }
            }
```

Comment: Unrelated to this error, I have to ask, why are you using memcached buckets? Even for an HA cache scenario, it is best to use Couchbase buckets.

Comment: @Kirk I tried with couchbase bucket, but i got the same error

Comment: I am not a .net developer, so I am not qualified to give you specific advice about code. That said, have you followed the getting started tutorials on the Couchbase web site that go over this stuff with code examples for you to download and learn from?

Comment: This was a version issue, when i updated to lastest couchbase server. it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a version issue, when Couchbase dll updated to lastest, it works fine